# UIImageView counts in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiimage

All,

I have this

```
@IBOutlet weak var ImageViewMain: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView9: UIImageView!
```

These are assigned in my storyboard.

I have a function like this :

func Staffphotos(quantity: Int)
{

```
self.ImageView1.image = image
var division : CGFloat = (self.ImageView1.frame.size.width / 2.0)
self.ImageView1.layer.cornerRadius = division
self.ImageView1.clipsToBounds = true
self.ImageView1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
self.ImageView1.layer.borderColor = colour.CGColor
self.view.addSubview(self.ImageView1)
```

}

This needs to be run x ammount of times dependent on (quantity : int). then it should fill the amount of slots (imageView1 - 8) accordling to (quantity : int).

any ideas of how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBOutlet weak var ImageViewMain: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView9: UIImageView!

var arrayOfImages = [UIImageView]()
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView1)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView2)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView3)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView4)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView5)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView6)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView7)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView8)
arrayOfImages.append(ImageView9)

func staffPhoto(imageView:UIImageView)
{
    imageView.image = image
    var division : CGFloat = (imageView.frame.size.width / 2.0)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = division
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    imageView.layer.borderColor = colour.CGColor
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
}

for var imageView in arrayOfImages
{
    staffPhoto(imageView)
}
```

Let me know if this works